# Glassfish 4 default servlet encoding

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, glassfish

**So this is the problem:**

> example.com:8080/txt/temp.txt

And here is the result:

> ÑÑ‚Ð¾ Ð½Ð¾Ð²Ñ‹Ð¹ Ñ„Ð°Ð¹Ð» that is a new file

**What I tried:**

glassfish-web.xml

```
<glassfish-web-app>
  <parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8"/>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet
</servlet-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>debug</param-name>
<param-value>0</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
<param-name>listings</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>fileEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

in domain/config/default-web.xml added to default servlet

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>fileEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

in glassfish4/bin/asadmin
added after -jar

> -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

No result. Please help me.

Comment: How to save temp.txt file? This file created you or server?

Comment: @herry I created in netbeans. Everything is fine when in browser I set utf8 encoding for this page.

Comment: You should not rely on defaults.  The servlet code should be setting the charset parameter of each response's Content-Type header.  Like this: `response.setContentType("text/plain; charset=UTF-8");` Your servlet might also want to write a [byte order mark](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#BOM) as the first character of the response.  This might help client systems to intuit the encoding of the saved file.  Plain text doesn't have any other way to identify its encoding, as far as I know.

Comment: @VGR But as far I remember we didn't have such problem with apache. We always used only utf8.

Comment: I believe when you set that default in Apache, Apache will modify the Content-Type of text/plain responses to include that charset.  Servlet containers are not allowed to do that.  And browsers are required to use a response's Content-Type above all other things.